# JNI eclipse Javah auto generate

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

Hi I am using javah to generate header file. I tried the following two ways but none of them works perfect for me.

Method 1: In bin/classes, I use

```
javah -jni com.example.test.NativeLib
```

it reports:

```
 Error: Could not find class file for 'com.example.test.NativeLib'.
```

But it works for me in sometimes (anyone knows why?).

Then I use the following way which is also very popular: In src/

```
javah -classpath ../bin/classes -jni com.example.test.NativeLib
```

it reports:

```
Error: Class org.opencv.core.Mat could not be found.
```

Then I add the OpenCV classpath:

```
javah -classpath ../bin/classes/:D:/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/java/bin/classes -jni com.example.test.NativeLib
```

it report:

```
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.example.test.NativeLib'.
```

again.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: CLASSPATH in windows is semicolon separated, not colon separated, so your last javah doesn't have the classpath that you expect. try with `../bin/classes/;D:/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/java/bin/classes` - I'm not certain about the direction of the `/` either, though shouldn't it be \?

Comment: I tried：javah -classpath ../bin/classes; D:/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/java/bin/classes -jni test.DenseSiftNativeLib. It reports:
-bash: D:/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/java/bin/classes: is a directory.

Comment: and now you have two problems. You're using `bash` rather than `cmd`, which interprets `;` as the end of the command, so you have to quote the classpath that you're passing, so `javah -classpath "../bin/classes/;D:/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/java/bin/classes" -jni com.example.test.NativeLib`

Comment: Solved! Thanks. Do you know why it works sometimes for the first method?

Comment: It's probably related to stale paths and the state of the build tree at the time you invoke the `javah`. I don't known enough about your build environment to be able to determine this with any degree of certainty. In general, though, you should be driving all this from build scripts in eclipse and not running it from the command line. Build scripts give you repeatable results, manual execution gives you headaches.

Comment: I tried several ways to config my eclipse with Ant. But I don't know how to run it correctly. I have encountered many problems that I can't handle myself. Do you know any reliable answer to config it?

Answer (score 0):

Easily point your class path to the place where your opencv java classes exist. javah needs this class in its classpath.

> org.opencv.core.Mat

So, easily feed it with this. If you have downloaded opencv4android from [official opencv Download center](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and extracted it in $opencv4android then you will find this.
$opencv4android/sdk/java/src

```
   -$opencv4android/
    |
    |
     ------sdk
           |
            -java
             |
               - src
                 |
                  - org
                    |
                     -- opencv
                        |
                        -- android
                        -- calib3d
                        -- core
                          |
                           -- Algorithm.java
                           -- Core.java
                              ......

                        -- engine
                        -- features2d
                        -- imgcodecs
                        -- ml
                        -- objdetect
                        -- photo
                        -- utils
                        -- video
                        -- videoio
```

FYI, I'm using opencv 3.0.0 version and Android studio on Windows 8. 
and this is whole the stuff javah is looking for.

### Windows Users

Open your terminal navigate to the following address

> [path to your project]\app\src\main

and write the following line of code:

```
javah -d jni -classpath [path to your android sdk]\platforms\android-19\android.jar;[path to your opencv4android]\sdk\java\src;..\..\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.test.NativeLib
```

Now javah has the access to all of the opencv classes.

### Linux users

Note that in writing out the classes in the classpath, you should seperate the search addresses with :(colon) instead of ;(semicolon).