# Opencv machine learning model pointer convert to jlong for App activity

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I have a Problem to convert c++ pointer to jlong. Here is my Situation: I use JNI to load pre-trained opencv machine learning model ANN_MLP(since there is no load function in opencv Android SDK) and the load function works well. But the Problem is I donn't know how to convert this c++ pointer to jlong, just as I want to return this pointer for my App. I googled but haven't fund so i just use memcpy to hold this pointer(maybe this is not the perfect method for it). One more wired Thing is, whatever I set the size of memcpy, the result buffer(here jlong resutl) has always a Offset with 8 from src buffer(here is model). Below is the code Piece what i wrote:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL reader_BridgeNativeModel_nativeCreateObject
(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass, jstring jFileName){

const char* jnamestr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jFileName, NULL);
string stdFileName(jnamestr);
Ptr<ml::ANN_MLP> model = Algorithm::load<ml::ANN_MLP>(stdFileName)
jlong result = 0;
memcpy(&result, model, 1);            // the size seems doesn't work, tried 4, 8, but got the same result as below outputs
LOGD("model  address :%p\t", &model);
LOGD("result address :%p\t", &result);
....
}

// the output of log always like this
model  address :0xbeed51e8
result address :0xbeed51e0
```

When I convert this returned jlong object as MLP pointer for prediction, I also have no idea how to convert it as model pointer:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL _BridgeNativeModel_nativePredict
(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass, jlong thiz, jstring jFileName,jlong src, jlong dst){
 Ptr<ml::ANN_MLP> model;
 printf("thiz %p\n", &thiz);
 memcpy(&model, thiz, 4);   // always crashed here, memcpy failed
 ....
 }
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.
Jian

Comment: I also had a look at this link:[ link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246265/opencv-ann-mlp-training-in-android) But it does't help me neither!

Comment: Maybe i didn't make it claerly. In other word, how to hold the loaded model for the caller.